# How to redirect from one view to another?

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

I have an `x` view that redirects me to some_name.html page.

This view needs to create a class that it is importing from other python file.

This view calls a specific function (algorithm) that has some logic in it.
lets say this func return a dictionary.

I want that view 'x' will redirect me to negotioate.html page with this dynamic return dictionary.

When the user gets the output he should choose from 3 options and basically trigger the algorithm again.

Meaning, I want in each of those trigger to display the user the algo output but **without** reidrecting me to other page, but **refreshing** the current one.

Comment: Looks like you are a bit confused with what *views* are.... and redirections too actually.  What do you mean by "an x view that redirects me to some_name.html page" ? You mean it _renders_ a "some_name.html" template ?

Comment: yes. basically it's looks something like that:
        return render(request, 'negotiation/negotiate.html', context)

Comment: @drobr that's definitly not what "redirect" means in web programming (http redirect means "go to this other url").

Comment: > This view needs to create a class that it is importing from other
> python file.

You probably means "create an instance of class" ?
> This view calls a specific function (algorithm)
> lets say this func return a dictionary.
> I want that view 'x' will redirect me to negotioate.html page with
> this dynamic return dictionary.

I assume you mean "will render template 'negociate.html' with this dictionnary as part of it's context". ?

Now what's totally unclear at this point is when you want your view to render "some_name.html" and when you want it to render "negociate.html".

Comment: > When the user gets the output he should choose from 3 options

Where do they come from ? And what are they used for ?

> and basically trigger the algorithm again.

Then why should the user select an option if it doesn't make any difference ?

Comment: > Meaning, I want in each of those trigger

which "trigger" ? You first use this word as a verb then as a noun, this really doesn't make your question clearer.

> to display the user the algo output 

Ain't that already what you were doing from the beginning ? 

> but without reidrecting me to other page, but refreshing the current one.

You just have to `return render(request, yourtemplate, yourcontext`) so I don't see what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', edit, name="edit"),
```

OR

Return :

```
return redirect('quizzes.views.quizView', quizNumber=quizNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can redirect from one view to another with data.

Try this code which I am using for my project also.

```
def notification_view(request,pk):
    notification_to_edit=notifications.objects.get(pk=pk)
    notification_to_edit.viewed = True
    notification_to_edit.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('taskdetail',kwargs={'pk':notification_to_edit.task_id.id}))
```

You need to use AJAX method to avoid page refresh. This view will reload the page, but code should work fine.